# Delphi Overbyte ICS THttpCli- How to set custom request header?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Is it possible to set a custom header with [ICS](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html?redirTo=/products/ics.html) `THttpCli` POST request?
I'm using ICS-V5 Distribution (Sep 12, 2009)

All I can see is a `RcvdHeader` property but there is no `SendHeader`.

P.S: I know about Indy. this is a question about ICS which is used in my current framework.

Comment: Yes, e.g. in the `OnBeforeHeaderSend` event you can modify the headers passed as the `Headers` string list parameter.

Comment: @TLama, Good catch :) why don't you post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the `OnBeforeHeaderSend` event you can modify the headers passed as the `Headers` string list parameter.

Thanks @TLama :)